# while loop issue, skips first look

Tags: php, while-loop

So I have a while loop with records from database, what I am trying to do is group by "coordinator" In this case I ordered the SQL query by coordinator so that I may be able to group in the loop. The problem is that it always skips the first row, I assume there should be something wrong in the logic of the loop, I just cant figure out how to fix this. I am trying to show a table for each coordinator found in the results but the first table is coming empty which it shouldn't. Here is the code I have. Thank you

```
$coordinator = '';

$start = true;
while($data = $rs->fetch_assoc()){


    if($data['email'] != $cordinator){


        $message .= TableHeader($fune[$i], $data['coordinator']);
        $message .= $rows;
        $message .= '</table>';     
        $message .= '<br><br>';

        echo $message;
        $message = '';
        $rows = '';


    }

    $rows .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$data['case_no'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['deceased_name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['notes'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    $start = false; 

    $coordinator = $data['email'];  

}
```

Comment: can you please show our table structure and query aswell ?

Comment: try to place `$row = ' ';` at outside of `if` statement

Answer (score 3):

Notice anything missing?

```
if($data['email'] != $cordinator){
                       ^---
```

v.s.

```
$coordinator = $data['email'];  
  ^^---
```

?

You should have gotten at least an undefined variable warning, which means you're running with display_errors and error_reporting off. They should NEVER be off on a debug/devel system. It's like stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I turn on all reporting, I did get undefined variable, but after fixing it still the results are not good. $rows is also undefined because the first time it loops it hasn't picked up any rows.